# How to model a table with few rows in star schema manner?

Tags: pentaho, data-modeling

I have two dimensions: location and date. There's one fact table (x) consisting of measures with respect to location and date. Now, I have a requirement for including target KPI measures for each of the 60 locations I have in location dimension table. So, each measure in the fact table (x) has a benchmark measure (KPI). I cannot add it in the fact table (x) because the KPI values would repeat all across the depth of the table.

How do I re-model the star schema to incorporate this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You could have two dimensions (date and location) and two fact tables (X and target KPI).

This is usually done in this way because the fact table with the real measure have more dimensions and rows, where the target/forecast has often less details.

I.e. A supermarket chain can fix monthly targets for each store, but it has sales data by store, day, product.

My suggestion is to have two separated tables.

Then if you will use often measures (from X table) and target KPIs together (showing deltas, delta percentage, etc.), then you can think about creating a third fact table (or a view, if performances allow that) to avoid joining between the other two fact tables every time you need that.

Comment: The problem is that the KPI table is at month level, the fact (X) is at day level, you need to aggregate the fact values at the month level before joining  them. The KPI table has to have location/month dimension. Of course the month will be parent of day.

Comment: I have done exactly the same as you have suggested. The target KPI fact table stores monthly KPI values and it has date keys borrowed from date dimension. So, the fact table consists of repeating KPI  values for each month multiplied by the number of days in that month. Basically, target KPI fact tables stores daily date keys and hence monthly target KPI repeat for each day in that month. That will cause performance as the data size grows. Any suggestion?

Comment: not really, this is the standard approach, then of course it depends on you database and the number of rows in your tables.

Comment: The target KPI values are set on monthly basis not based on any formula. So, I cannot perform any formula on these values. I am thinking of creating a month dimension referencing date dimension. So, it becomes snowflake schema. This will drastically reduce the number of rows in target KPI fact table. The number of rows will be (number of location * 12) instead of (number of location * number of days in each month). How does it sound?

Comment: I didn't say anything about a formula to calculate the KPI, but formulas based on KPIs. You can have a snowflake schema or a star schema (this is usually important for the reporting tool), this is not related to the granularity of the facts tables that you have and different fact tables can have different granularity. As you can see in my comment I was suggesting the KPI fact table at location/month level. So it sounds right :)

Comment: Sorry, I was tied up other priorities. Thanks for sharing the knowledge :)